# Excel - Change presentation of two fields with pivot

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I don't even know what to phrase the question, but I this source data:

[image]

and I simple want to change the presentation, so that I have a column for each customer. The end result should look like this:

[image]

I thought this could be done with a pivot table, but when I transform it into a pivot then the cells are empty, because I don't have a value field and I don't know how to calculate it.

Who can help me?

Comment: You can actually achieve that using Pivot Table for presentation purposes only. Because these doesn't give any counts or sums. etc

Comment: Can you give some directs how to achieve that?

Comment: But let me know, one thing, this will not reflect any counts just for presenting, that each food items are present for the customers, is that good for you, so shall post in answers?

Comment: Well, yes, for me it does not matter if it is 0 or 1 or just an 'X'. I am only interested in the occurence.

Comment: I have posted one formula solution if you like or helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general purpose of a presentation, you can use the <kbd>Pivot Tables</kbd> for the required output, by placing the <kbd>Customer</kbd> once in <kbd>Columns</kbd> area and once in <kbd>Values</kbd> area.

---

Once you place them in <kbd>Values</kbd> area, select the region which shows the counts and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

---

On doing above it opens the <kbd>Format Cells</kbd> window --> From <kbd>Number</kbd> Tab --> Under <kbd>Category</kbd> --> Click <kbd>Custom</kbd>
and type by removing and hit OK.

```
[=1]"X";
```

---

This will change the `1s` to <kbd>X</kbd> but note that since cell formatting is facade the formula bar would always read as `1` but the pivot table display will be showing as <kbd>X</kbd>

---

[image]

---

An alternative approach using <kbd>Excel Formulas</kbd> viz.

<kbd>LET( )</kbd> | <kbd>TOROW( )</kbd> | <kbd>UNIQUE( )</kbd> | <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> | <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd> | <kbd>VSTACK( )</kbd> | <kbd>IF( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,B2:B9,
     b,A2:A9,
     ua,TOROW(UNIQUE(a)),
     ub,UNIQUE(b),
     c,MMULT(--(TOROW(b)=ub),--(a=ua)),
     HSTACK(VSTACK("Food",ub),
     VSTACK(ua,IF(c>0,"X",""))))
```

---

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding the customer to, both, columns and values is what I was not aware of.

Comment: @EricJobs Sounds good, I have posted a formula solution. Hope you like it. I use `MMULT()` a lot, very powerful function.